# ASP.net MVC Error: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Company' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am getting this error after deleted one of my tables from db, after changed my model and before updated the database. I had then to delete and recreate migration files and delete the migration history from db. Now when I try to create a new company in the db I get this error even if I don't explicitly add the primary key value. I have wasted a couple of hours trying to understand what is going on and reading solutions for this error, but none worked for me. This worked before as it is. Please help!

The Model:

```
public class Company
{

    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

 //....other properties of the company follows here....
    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
 }
```

In the Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Name,Address,PhoneNo,Email")] Company company)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Companies.Add(company);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "CompaniesRolesMV");
        }

        return View(company);
    }
```

UPDATE: I forgot to mention that I have 2 one-to-many relations from Company to Role and to Employee. Added fluent API to set DELETE ON CASCADE false with model builder. Tried all suggestions from your comments and I thank you a lot for them. I have another error now:

Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'CompanyId', table 'aspnet-DevEnvExamProject-20161213094625.dbo.Companies'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.

Debugged it and the company object from Create method added 0 to CompanyId property. I forced it to take value 1, the same error!

Comment: Try adding the [Key] attribute above the property `CompanyId` ?

Comment: Tried! I have the same error... Also tried : [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] with no success.

Comment: I think it might be some inconsistency between the db and db configuration files but can't figure it out.

Comment: I agree with your presumption. The error indicates that your database is configured with CompanyId as an Identity column. But as you say, even adding the [Key] attribute to the class property does not resolve the error occurring at `db.SaveChanges()`. You might try cleaning your solution and verifying project references are up-to-date.

Comment: cleaned the code.... what do you mean by references are up-to-date, can you give more details?

Comment: If you have your EntityFramework model compiled and are referencing it as a binary source, make sure that is up-to-date. If your project references are direct (like in your solution), then that shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: I found a problem in my fluent API modelBuilder: I put the entities inverted. I used this because I have more than one many-to-many relations from Company table and that gave another error: some multiple paths relations...can't remember. Now for some reason the Create method from the controller sets 0 for the CompanyId value and this throws another error: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'CompanyId'. I have to figure out why sets 0....

Comment: Keep in mind, if you have an int value with `MyClassId` attribute on it and no other PK is specified, EntityFramework will automatically make it the PK.  Just one of the reasons I hate EF.

Comment: This is the convention and the idea for primary key. I know that.

Comment: Since Code First migrations being used, probably you want to set fluent mapping to identity column inside `OnModelCreating` or any other method accepts `DbModelBuilder` parameter: `modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().Property(p => p.CompanyId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);` in addition with `[DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity‌​)]` attribute on `CompanyId` property.

Comment: I will try. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Moved all my code to a new project and "magically" the issue was gone. Thank you everyone for your help and suggestions!

Afterwards I found out the reason of the issue as Pavvy told me.

Comment: You should have checked what it shows in table's column properties. It must be autoincreament = true by default. In your case, table may have not created properly, and that property could have became false. It happens sometime. The correct way to resolve this issue is, drop that tables from code and run the migration. and again recreate that table through migration only.

Comment: You are right! I checked in the server explorer->table column prop.->Identity Increment : 0. I also noticed something else: Is Identity: False. Thank you for figuring this out for me. I can accept this as the solution if you want.

Answer (score 0):

if you make changes on your tables "using code first using a database" mode and want to apply it without replacing all the code
you can delete `Models.[DBContext]` and make another one using the same `Models.[DBContext]` name.